# LINQ causing my obfuscator to break

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ that is causing my obfuscator to break.

```
.Where(f => f.FileName == fileName).OrderByDescending(f => f.Position).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there another way I could reword this LINQ statement to test against my obfuscator?

I've reported the bug, but it could take 1-2 months to fix, so I need to try recode this LINQ in the meantime.

**Update:**

The exact cause in the LINQ is :

```
.Where(f => f.FileName == fileName)
```

Answer (score 3):

How exactly does the problem manifest? Since the C# expression compiler (used in the LINQ above) uses the memberinfo tokens *directly* (rather than relying on strings as reflection), I can't see that you could do any better. Likewise, *assuming* it is an IL obfuscator (not a source obfuscator), re-writing it as a query expression should achieve nothing, nix, zip, zero and nada. You you can try...

```
var first = (from f in [whatever]
             where f.FileName == fileName
             orderby f.Position descending
             select f).FirstOrDefault();
```

What exactly happens?

---

Edit based on comment: if the problem is the "capture", you could try manually building the expression with a constant (instead of a captured value) - where `Foo` is your type:

```
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "f");
    var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "FileName"),
        Expression.Constant(filename));
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(body, param);
```

then use:

```
    .Where(predicate).OrderByDescending(f => f.Position).FirstOrDefault();
```

The problem, of course, is convincing it that "FileName" and `Foo.FileName` must stay the same...

---

And here's a version that doesn't need the string:

```
    Expression<Func<Foo, string>> liftFileName = foo => foo.FileName;
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(liftFileName.Body, Expression.Constant(filename)),
        liftFileName.Parameters);
```

Comment: When I do a release build, the post build event for the obfuscator fails with a reference to undefined class, and another error - Error occured during processing of input file '[sourceFile]' --> ilasm.exe: warning -- Nested class has non-nested visibility (0x00000001), changed to nested (0x00000002).

Comment: @JL - hmmm... that sounds like the "fileName" capture - we *might* be able to fix that; two seconds...

Comment: Seems like your LINQ has the same problem as the original. Exact same error. I also decided to do a quick empty foreach loop through the collection, and that behaved and compiled.

Comment: @Marc, Is that the exact code I need to use? Can you explain the theory please a bit more?

Comment: Where clause has some invalid arguments.

Comment: @JL - the C# compiler uses object capture. What I have posted *should* work, or something very much like it. I've just validated it against a test model I have locally, and it worked first time.

Comment: test C#: `var list = ctx.Table1s.Where(predicate).ToList();` - generated TSQL: `SELECT [t0].[FileName] FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[FileName] = @p0`

Comment: @Marc, I should have stated up front that I am using Linq for objects, not SQL sorry!

Comment: @JL; then just call `.Compile()` on the predicate.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to exlcude the .FileName and .Position properties from obfuscation(renaming).

To avoid having to do this on every query, switch to an obfuscator which supports LINQ-to-* such as [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm).

Answer (score 0):

In the presence of a broken tool, it is impossible to provide a guaranteed fix. You'll have to tinker with it. Try swapping `Where` and `OrderBy...`. Perhaps `FirstOrDefault()` is breaking, so maybe do that part by hand. In fact, even `OrderBy...` can probably be replace with a sort. There's a bunch of other stuff you could try.

BTW, Is this LINQ-to-SQL or LINQ-to-Objects? They behave in fundamentally different ways.

Comment: LINQ to Objects I think, I am traversing an collection class.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I had this problem this morning. I'm using [.NET Reactor](http://www.eziriz.com/) which doesn't natively support obfuscating my POCO's for LINQ to Entities.

If your obfuscator respects the `System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute`, you can use it to exclude your entities and DbContext from obfuscation.

```vb
<Obfuscation(ApplyToMembers:=True, Exclude:=True)>
```

If you have heavier domain objects with other code that you'd like to obfuscate, the minimum exclusions appear to be:

1. DbContext class name
2. Property name for each DbSet
3. Entity class name
4. Mapped entity properties

In these cases, you only have to use the more lightweight form.

```vb
<Obfuscation(Exclude:=True)> Public Property ID As Integer
```